# Tabs and Url bar on same toolbar in web browser

Tags: browser, web

Does anyone know of a web browser that puts the tabs, url bar, back/forward buttons, etc... on the same toolbar by default? I know this is possible in Firefox but it never looks very good. Something like this:

[image]

Or maybe, do you know of a theme/extension for Firefox or Google Chrome that puts them all on the same bar and still keeps its good looks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mozilla Labs: Prospector - OneLiner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-oneLiner/)

It's a Mozilla Labs Project, so there is a chance if it is successful, it will land up as a default feature of Firefox.

[image: Mozilla Labs: Prospector - OneLiner]

Comment: also, it dosen't need a reboot, so its easy to try out. I use it now

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer, as it happens.

[image]